# Oracle find out what the "type" is

Tags: oracle

When reading some legacy code on oracle, I often come across something like:

```
select ... from a.b ...
```

Is there a quick way to find out what `a` is?
`a` can be an user, package, database link, synonym, etc, etc....

I often have to dig around `all_object` and check. If it is not there, I would have to check for `all_users`, etc... I find this method a bit cumbersome and clumsy. Is there any other quick way to check?

Comment: What editor are you using? If you have plsql developer, you could use the describe option to see the objects.

Comment: `a` cannot be a package or a database link, because [syntax diagram](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6) is different: package contains only a function as a `select`able object, while function invocation may be recognized by parentheses in the call; a DB link has this format `table@dblink`. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am using Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: @astentx Just want to minimise my time to find out what type it is. Sometimes I thought `a` could be an user but then it turns out to be a synonym. I just want to find the 'source' of `b` quickly without fiddling around `all_object`, `all_user`, etc...